# Обособление сравнительного оборота внутри обособленного определения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот, обороты-с-как

Сравнительный оборот "***как сорок тысяч ос***" в приведенном предложении обособлен. На какое **правило Розенталя** можно сослаться, чтобы объяснить постановку запятой перед союзом КАК? Является ли такое обособление обязательным?

*Наконец  он закончил потрошить мечом диван и обрушился вниз, **злобный, как сорок тысяч ос**.*

Спасибо.

**Контекст:**

– А ну встать! – заорал Ш., двумя ногами заскакивая на диван.
– Ты уверен, что этого хочешь? – уточнил М., с вежливым вниманием разглядывая его ноги.
– Встать!!!
– Ну сам попросил, – ответил М.  и встал с покорным вздохом.
Рассчитал верно. Ш. был легче его. Секунду спустя он уже барахтался, прижатый диваном к потолку, и пытался выхватить меч…
*Наконец  он закончил потрошить диван и обрушился вниз, **злобный, как сорок тысяч ос.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параграф Розенталя «[**Сравнительный оборот**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147,3)», уверен, вам очень хорошо знаком. Думаю, что ничего «особо особенного» в предложении автора нет: ***как сорок тысяч ос*** имеет значение уподобления, для обстоятельства образа действия оборот слишком большой, тесная связь с определением ***злобный*** не улавливается. Зато есть четкое ударение на этом прилагательном и пауза после него (читать в одну фразу не получается).

Конечно, в этом параграфе нет примеров, настолько похожих на данный, чтобы сказать: «Вот, смотри́те – нужно писать так». Но есть следующие (тоже с прилагательными):

*Перстами лёгкими, **как сон,** моих зениц коснулся он* (П.);
*Он удивительно хорошо себя держит, осторожен, **как кошка*** (Т.);
*…Пили бабушкины наливки — жёлтую, **как золото,** тёмную, **как дёготь,** и зелёную* (М. Г.);
*На самом дне, сухом и жёлтом, **как медь,** лежали огромные плиты глинистого камня* (Т.).

Третий и четвертый примеры содержат обособленные конструкции, внутри которых обособляется сравнительный оборот. Наиболее близок к нашему случаю последний (хотя перед союзом ***как*** даже паузу делать не хочется – перебор будет).

Является ли такое обособление обязательным? При другой структуре предложения – нет, но переделывать его не имеет смысла: всё в порядке, запятая на месте.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, за ответ. Меня интересовало не столько конкретное предложение,как вся тема, связанная с обособлением сравнительного оборота внутри обособленного определения. Из примеров у Розенталя можно сделать вывод, что само определение может быть как обособленным, так и необособленным, но сравнительный оборот,  как правило, обособляется. Но вот (с вашей помощью) НАШЛОСЬ примечание Розенталя (после пункта 3.1), где он говорит о смысловой отнесенности оборота, которую надо учитывать, например:  Я мчался на лихом коне, КАК ВЕТЕР волен и один .

Comment: Ну а в приведенном предложении оборот не будет обособляться, если относится к устойчивым  сравнениям (злобный как черт). Возможен, вероятно,  и такой вариант: Перстами,  лёгкими как сон, моих зениц коснулся он.

Comment: Спасибо и вам! Да, хотел также отметить, что оборот не относится к фразеологизмам (или не настолько устойчив и известен). И да, если бы оборот стоял в середине и было непонятно, к чему его относить, то запятая бы не ставилась (правильное примечание :)).

Comment: Если честно, то там такая история. Мне нужна была ссылка на правило, как ведут себя сравнительные обороты в обособленном определении, а я это правило никак не найду. И в то же время помню, что была какая-то информация по этой теме.  Тогда я решила задать вопрос, чтобы ответ был с этой ссылкой.  Ну и жду, как «птицелов»: вдруг  кто-нибудь  ответит. Но ждать пришлось долго :))  А сейчас я думаю, что кроме это примечания ничего Розенталь не написал, так что придется примеры обобщать.  Так что еще раз спасибо вам за ответ.